# Seeing a TextField as a subview of a UICell

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added a TextField to a UICell in order to allow a user to change the TextLabel of said cell. Everything works fine in that the keyboard appears and the TextLabel changes to the correct value when I press return. I can't, however, SEE the text as it is being edited. Here is my code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {


     [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
     UITableViewCell *aCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSString *aCategory = aCell.textLabel.text;
     [[aCell detailTextLabel] setText:aCategory];


     [aCell setEditing:YES animated:YES];
     UITextField *userText =[[UITextField alloc] init];
     userText.tag = indexPath.row;
     [aCell addSubview:userText];
     NSArray *test =[aCell subviews];
     NSLog(@"I have %d many subviews",[test count]);
     userText.alpha=1.0;
     [userText setDelegate:self];
     userText.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
     [aCell bringSubviewToFront:userText];
     [userText becomeFirstResponder];


 }
```

I would like to do it without custom cells if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *aCategory = aCell.textLabel.text;
    [[aCell detailTextLabel] setText:aCategory];

    UITextField *userText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:aCell.textLabel.frame];
    userText.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    userText.font = aCell.textLabel.font;
    userText.text = aCell.textLabel.text;
    aCell.textLabel.text = nil;
    userText.tag = indexPath.row;
    [aCell addSubview:userText];

    [userText setDelegate:self];
    userText.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [aCell bringSubviewToFront:userText];
    [userText becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    aCell.textLabel.text = textField.text;
    [textField removeFromSuperview];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```